# Trigger a Function at a specific time

Tags: javascript, jwt

The problem is I have JWT Authentication implemented in my app (C# backend / JS Front End). I want to automatically redirect the user to the login page (kick them out) once their token expiration is exceeded.

I'm looking into how to achieve this, and I've come to the conclusion that I want an elegant way to trigger a function at specific time given a date.

`const tokenExpiresIn = 10000; // <- token expires in 10 seconds`

**Option 1**

Good ol' `setTimeout`

`setTimeout( () => { /* do redirect */ }, tokenExpiresIn);`

**Option 2**

Always be checking for token expiration

`setInterval( () => { /* is the current time greater than the expiry time */  }, 1000);`

I could see **Option 1** being more efficient as I'm not constantly executing a check (like **Option 2** is) but if I refresh the token, I would have to add code to clear / update the `interval`. However, **Option 2** is kind of appealing because I already have logic in place that updates the token / expiration via local storage.

Are there any other options in regards to an elegant way to trigger a function that redirects a page at a specific time?

I already validate the token on every request to the server so that part is covered, just trying to think of a remote user ban / idle user scenario.

Comment: Do you have page refreshes or reloads in your application?

Comment: Nah, it's a single page app. I do validate the token on every http request though. Which is to say the backend is covered, just trying to provide support for auto-redirects like modern applications have (like online banking, etc..)

Comment: Because the JWT will expire at a specific time, I would suggest that you configure a `setTimeout` based on some basic arithmetic. If the page reloads/refreshes it should trigger this routine again. FWIW, `setInterval` isn't particularly expensive when executed every second and just doing a date comparison.

Comment: use your backend to your advantage here.  When a new request is made, just write a helper function to inspect the return value, if say the return value is a 401, redirect the user to the login page...with a callback to return to the page they were on once they re-authenticate?

Comment: Yea, the problem is, not every page / action could have an HTTP Request. For example, they could load up a page, get a bunch of data loaded into the client and walk away from their computer. If it's been 5 minutes or whatever, I want to kick them out by redirecting and logging them out so they are forced to log back in and do whatever they were doing when they are actually at their desk.

Comment: ... But, I am totally going to introduce SignalR to cover the ban-user scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Both setInterval and setTimeout are great, and gets triggered according to their contracts.

Since you are looking for more options, here is what I had done for an internal site.

1. Use an interceptor for all the API responses to trap errors. In your case 40x.
2. Perform a setInterval on the auth api every x seconds. (traffic may get impacted)
3. Use the local storage for the last time page was loaded and perform a forceful redirect after x minutes.

I hope it helps.